# Run script daily with cron and create compressed log file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Im trying to run PHP script on this location on every 15 minutes

```
0,5,10,15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php  /var/www/html/adform.php
```

and to put results of the script in specific folder in specific file and to compress it daily. Is it possible and how? Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible.

Instead of running `/usr/local/bin/php` every 15 minutes, why not replace that call with a shell script which does everything you described?

This shell script would run your php script, pipe the output to a file somewhere on your system which you can then compress.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. Can you give me some examples how to do that shell script

Comment: Hi Milos. I am not going to write the script for you as it is very basic. There are some hints in my answer describing what it needs to do. I.E., pipe output of the `php` command to a file and then compress that file using your preferred  data compression tool. See: `tar`, `zip`.

Comment: @MilosMarkovic How did you get on with the script? Did this approach work for you?

Comment: Yap Lewis i tried with the .sh instead of php and successfully set cron with log. Tnx